aiogram 3.13.1 | Telegram Код для игнорирования предыдущих сообщений, когда бот выключен
Какой код нужно вписать в бота, чтобы он игнорировал предыдущие сообщения от юзера?
Бот выключается >> юзер присылает сообщения >> бот включается и должен игнорировать все сообщения присланные, пока бот был отключен

покажите пример как вы пытались сделать, и где именно возникает проблема

Опять одинаковые вопросы поплыли. Вчера-позавчера был аналогичный вопрос (вроде не от вас)...

А вот и он

Я вас порадую, там дискуссия поживее будет, и там даже черновик кода есть

@Chaos_Sower, но на дубликат без ответа с положительным результатом не тянет, к сожалению..

await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)

см. документацию к delete_webhook.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
